# cakephp 2 - dynamic content on the homepage

Tags: cakephp

I'm using cakephp 2.3.8 and I want to create custom content for my homepage. I'm having trouble getting anything from the Pages Controller to the home.ctp view

In my Pages Controller I've created a home function :

```
public function home() {
    $test = 'test';
    $this->set(compact('test'));
}
```

But when I go to home and check with the debug kit I can see there is no $test variable.

How do I get information from the controller to the view for the home page?

Comment: have you tried `$this->set($test,'test');`?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that the default route for the pages controller is causing you trouble:

```
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

So when you go to /pages/home, it thinks it's got to execute the 'display' action still.

Try putting a route above it like this:

```
 Router::connect('/pages/home', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home'));
 Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

That way, the home page will render your home action, and all others will render the default 'display' action.

That's all in `/app/config/routes.php`.